# ios NSPredicate crash when creating it

Tags: ios, crash, nsstring, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm using this code to fetch something from Core data:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Friend"];

NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"identifier == %@", [[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
req.predicate = predicate;

req.fetchLimit = 1;
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSArray *tmp = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&requestError];
```

But it crashes on

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"identifier == %@", [[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]];
```

If i remove the stringFromMD5 method call, it works.

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                     @"identifier == %@", [friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

Any ideea why?
Thanks

Comment: what is output of `[[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]`?

Comment: this is the log of predicateString "identifier == 4ccb5c86bfe2407cbdb4142850c877ae"

Comment: You shouldn't use `stringWithFormat:` and build the string for the predicate yourself, as it might require some different syntax that the `predicateWithFormat:` method builds, but not NSString. For example, strings are wrapped in `"`, thats why your predicate fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please, try the following way, it might work well:

```
NSPredicate *_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"identifier", [[friendInfo objectForKey:@"id"] stringFromMD5]];
```

Comment: I didn't edit it, but the %K substitution of the key path is unnecessary.  Also, since it's an example, a clearer variable name than `_pred` wouldn't go amiss. :)

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore but know the predicate loged is `identifier == "4ccb5c86bfe2407cbdb4142850c877ae"` and that doesn't match the search

Comment: @DaveDeLong okay I'm using a full word now for the variable's name. I'm hoping the underscore `_` would not be problem, because it could be used for any private variable. I agree with you the `%K` is not necessary but this is the regular way. if you wanted to be consistent in naming variable... :)